# Методы перебора md5 при известных входящих параметрах

Tags: безопасность, md5, decrypt

Перерыл весь гугл, осталось обратиться только сюда.

В общем, стоит задача - подобрать значение md5 хеша.

Особенность подбора состоит в том, что есть все входящие значения хеша, но не известна последовательность, в которой при хешировании они ставятся. К тому же, есть возможность того, что какое то из значений может и не входить в хеш.

Собственно, вопрос заключается в следующем - есть ли готовые реализации, для работы с подобными случаями?

Comment: Готовые - не уверен. Но по сути вы имеете алфавит не из отдельных байт, а из групп байт. Дальше - перебор по алфавиту, но подставляются не байты, а группы байт.

Comment: ну вам по сути генератор всех перестановок с возможностью пропуска элементов нужен, а md5 к нему прикрутить не проблема. А по алгоритмам перестановок тут куча ответов уже есть, поищите их